# ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

When returning an object from an arrow function, it seems that it is necessary to use an extra set of `{}` and a `return` keyword because of an ambiguity in the grammar.

That means I can’t write `p => {foo: "bar"}`, but have to write `p => { return {foo: "bar"}; }`.

If the arrow function returns anything other than an object, the `{}` and `return` are unnecessary, e.g.: `p => "foo"`.

`p => {foo: "bar"}` returns `undefined`.

A modified `p => {"foo": "bar"}` throws *“`SyntaxError`: unexpected token: '`:`'”*.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: I'm not clear when to use return keyword and when not to use it, JS being very very flexible creates loads of bugs for new users of this language. I wish it was as strict like "Java" language

Comment: arrow functions is the the worst feature of es6 in terms of code readability. hate them so much.

Answer (score 1426, accepted):

You must wrap the returning object literal into parentheses. Otherwise curly braces will be considered to denote the function’s body. The following works:

```
p => ({ foo: 'bar' })
```

You don't need to wrap any other expression into parentheses:

```
p => 10
p => 'foo'
p => true
p => [1,2,3]
p => null
p => /^foo$/
```

and so on.

Reference: [MDN - Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)

Comment: I'm curious *why* the parens make a difference.

Comment: @wrschneider because without parens js parser thinks that its a function body, not an object, and foo is [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: @wrschneider more specifically, in terms of AST nodes, using parentheses denotes an expression statement, in which an object expression can exist, whereas by default, curly braces are interpreted as a block statement.

Comment: No idea why this works, but if you want to use the value of `p` as key for the object literal, this is how you do it: `p => ({ [p]: 'bar' })`. Without the `[]`, it'll either be `undefined` or literally the letter `p`.

Comment: @DanMan It's called [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and it's a feature of object literals.

Comment: why we don't have to use return keyword inside parenthesis ?

Comment: @vikramvi Because `p => ({ foo:  'bar' })` is the same as `p => { return { foo: 'bar' }; }`. It's a shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 79):

You may wonder, why the syntax is valid (but not working as expected):

```
var func = p => { foo: "bar" }
```

It's because of [JavaScript's label syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

So if you transpile the above code to ES5, it should look like:

```
var func = function (p) {
  foo:
  "bar"; //obviously no return here!
}
```

Comment: Labels are such a seldom used and esoteric feature. Do they REALLY have any value? I feel like they should be deprecated and eventually removed.

Comment: @Kenmore See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names/55934491#55934491 - backwards compatibility. *Browsers will refuse to implement a feature which breaks existing sites*

Comment: @Kenmore you can exit from nested loops if they are labeled. Not often used but definitely useful.

Answer (score 24):

If the body of the arrow function is wrapped in curly braces, it is not implicitly returned. Wrap the object in parentheses. It would look something like this.

```
p => ({ foo: 'bar' })
```

By wrapping the body in parens, the function will return `{ foo: 'bar }`.

Hopefully, that solves your problem. If not, I recently wrote an article about Arrow functions which covers it in more detail. I hope you find it useful. [Javascript Arrow Functions](https://paulmcbride.net/javascript-arrow-functions/)

Comment: why we don't have to use return keyword inside parenthesis ?

Comment: Because `p => ({ foo:  'bar' })` is transpiled into `p => { return { foo: 'bar' }; }`. It's a shorthand syntax.

Comment: Arrow functions implicitly return the expression on the right side of the arrow. eg `p => p * 2` will return the result of `p * 2`. The exception to this rule is when the expression on the right side is wrapped in curly braces, then you have to return yourself.

Answer (score 12):

### Issue:

When you do are doing:

```
p => {foo: "bar"}
```

JavaScript interpreter thinks you are opening a multi-statement code block, and in that block, you have to explicitly mention a return statement.

### Solution:

If your **arrow function expression** has a **single statement**, then you can use the following syntax:

```
p => ({foo: "bar", attr2: "some value", "attr3": "syntax choices"})
```

But if you want to have **multiple statements** then you can use the following syntax:

```
p => {return {foo: "bar", attr2: "some value", "attr3": "syntax choices"}}
```

*In above example, first set of curly braces opens a multi-statement code block, and the second set of curly braces is for dynamic objects. In multi-statement code block of arrow function, you have to explicitly use return statements*

For more details, check [Mozilla Docs for JS Arrow Function Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

## ES6 Arrow Function returns an Object

> the right ways

1. normal function return an object

```js
const getUser = user => {
  // do something
  const {name, age} = user;
  return { name, age };
};

const user = { name: "xgqfrms", age: 21 };

console.log(getUser(user));
// {name: "xgqfrms", age: 21}
```

2. (js expressions)

```js
const getUser = user => ({ name: user.name, age: user.age });

const user = { name: "xgqfrms", age: 21 };

console.log(getUser(user));
// {name: "xgqfrms", age: 21}
```

### explain

> If you were to rewrite this function expression as an arrow function, you might be tempted to simply translate it just like we did in the previous example, like this:

```js
let square = n => {
  square: n * n;
};
```

> When you call square, though, you'll notice the function doesn't work as intended. No matter which input value you pass, you'll get undefined as a return value. Why is that?

> The issue with the arrow function is that the parser doesn't interpret the two braces as an object literal, but as a block statement. Within that block statement, the parser sees a label called square which belongs to the expression statement n * n. Since there's no return statement at all, the returned value is always undefined.

> To be precise, the body of the function consists of a block statement whose statement list contains a single statement, a labeled statement. Its body is an expression statement holding the binary expression. There's no return statement.

### refs

https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions/issues/220

https://mariusschulz.com/blog/returning-object-literals-from-arrow-functions-in-javascript

Answer (score -8):

You can always check this out for more custom solutions:

```
x => ({}[x.name] = x);
```

Comment: This won’t even return a new object. The object you create there is discarded. This has little to do with this question.