# Converting javascript array of objects to array of other objects using map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, typescript

I want to convert one array to another kind of array.
Actually I am using typescript.
What am I doing wrong here:

```
//terminals is an array of objects. 
    groupOptions = terminals.map(trm => {
                id: trm.TerminalID, 
                text: trm.TerminalName, 
                selected: true
            });
```

intelisence complains about the body of the curly brackets. With them I meant an object, probably intellisence thinks its anonymous method body. How can I workaround this?

Comment: better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the curly brackets with parenthesis like this:

```
    //terminals is an array of objects. 
    groupOptions = terminals.map(trm => ({
                id: trm.TerminalID, 
                text: trm.TerminalName, 
                selected: true
            }) );
```

Problem is that the JavaScript runtime picks up the curly brackets as beginning/end of a function.

Comment: Its not just the IDE. The JavaScript runtime does the same, so its a *syntax error* even in ES6 raw (no TypeScript)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll update my answer

Comment: most elegant, thanks