# React JSX let syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, put

Trying to do a `PUT` request to update my `API` (which is `Rails`) and can't make it happen.

This is what I have

Building has many rooms, so I need

```
    let data = {
      building: {
        id: 1
        rooms: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: Vodkin
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: Petrov
          }
        ]
      }
```

I need

```
    building => {id => 1, rooms => [{id => 1, name => Vodkin}, {id => 2, name => Petrov}]}
```

It does not give me nested object with arrays.

How do I do this in JSX syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: Wrap the `{}` in  `()`

Comment: Hi James and thanks! Did you mean all braces or .. ?

Comment: You need to wrap the entire object in parenthesis, otherwise it is interpreted as a code block. Look at the question I linked for details.

Comment: Why are you using arrow functions in the first place?

Comment: Hi Aaron! This is console output (i've copied from backend server). In fact I need just nested object with array as written above.

Comment: James, does not work :( I've tried to put something else into rooms. rooms: ['123', '123] and it gives me [] as output however it is simple array.. This is primitive challenge, I just need to do whole model-model update (first model has many other models.. ) and I just need to construct it accordingly in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, decided to split all into smaller chunks and update them separately.. I think this is the best practise for react.