# Strange syntax error with map and arrow functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Never seen this one before:

```
.flatMap(obj => {
        return removeOneLine(this)
            .map(l => {l:l,id:obj.id});
```

I want to map the result, but of course, I guess JS doesn't know if this is an object or the function body.

Is doing the following the only way to avoid a syntax error (because it's ambiguous to the engine):

```
  .flatMap(obj => {
           return removeOneLine(this)
                .map(l => {
                    return {l: l, id: obj.id}
                });
        })
```

is this ambiguity in this situation normal, any way to mitigate besides what I just did above?

Comment: Btw, you changed two things in your code, you removed the `return` keyword. It's unclear if that's just a "typo" or part of your actual change. Either way it's completely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to remove that return statement, edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have the curlies for a single-statement fat-arrow function?

You don't need curly braces around the function bodies or an explicit `return` statement. You do, however, need to put parentheses around the object literal to prevent its being interpreted as a function body.

```
.flatMap( obj=> removeOneLine(this).map(l => ({ l: l, id: obj.id })) )
```

Comment: I guess because I wanted to put it on multiple lines? I guess it works even if I put it on multiple lines, idk

Comment: You might want to explain what you changed instead of asking a (rather unrelated) question ;)

Comment: @FelixKling huh? :) this was all about the answer given by Mark, and it is a duplicate question

Comment: aka, this does answer the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object

Comment: Fair enough, I updated my answer, but you're right, it's a dupe.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: My comment was directed at Mark, not you.

Comment: ahh, got it sorry about that