# ESLint error Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using ESlint in my project. I am getting the error ** Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body** from this function

```
const toggleDrawer = (state) => {
 return {
 ...state,
 drawerExpanded: !state.drawerExpanded,
 };
};
```

Can anyone suggest me how to handle this ESlint error?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: @torazaburo I checked that. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the object in parenthesis `()`

```
const toggleDrawer = (state) => ({
 ...state,
 drawerExpanded: !state.drawerExpanded,
});
```

Also check if you have : `arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]` in es-lint

Comment: did you try setting `arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]` in es-lint??

Comment: Adding arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed", { "requireReturnForObjectLiteral": true }] fixed.