# Convert values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with `String` values that I want to convert to `Date`, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

How should I correctly do this conversion and return the same object structure?

```
array = [
    {
        end: "2017-05-18T09:00:00.000Z",
        start: "2017-05-18T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        end: "2017-05-19T07:00:00.000Z",
        start: "2017-05-19T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        end: "2017-05-20T08:00:00.000Z",
        start: "2017-05-20T07:00:00.000Z"
    }
]

result = array.map((element) => {
  {
    end: new Date(element.end),
    start: new Date(element.start),
  }
})
```

Comment: youre missing an *return*

Comment: You can wrap the `{}` in parentheses.... `array.map(element) => ({ end, start})` otherwise you need to use `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either do:

```
result = array.map(element => ({
 end: new Date(element.end),
start: new Date(element.start),
}));
```

OR:

```
result = array.map(element => {
  return {
    end: new Date(element.end),
    start: new Date(element.start),
  };
})
```

May have a look at [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because javascript here thinks `{ end: new Date(element.end), start: new Date(element.start), }` is a code block.
Change it to

```
result = array.map((element) => {
  return {
    end: new Date(element.end),
    start: new Date(element.start),
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

You're missing a return.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap an object in parenthesis ad return value.

```js
let array = [{ end: "2017-05-18T09:00:00.000Z", start: "2017-05-18T06:00:00.000Z" }, { end: "2017-05-19T07:00:00.000Z", start: "2017-05-19T06:00:00.000Z" }, { end: "2017-05-20T08:00:00.000Z", start: "2017-05-20T07:00:00.000Z" }],
    result = array.map(element => ({
        end: new Date(element.end),
        start: new Date(element.start),
    }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To return object using the arrow function you need extra brackets, like below:

```
results = array.map(el => ({ end: new Date(el.end), start: new Date(el.start) }) )
```