# unexpected token : using map to form array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to produce this

```
[
        {name: "james", age: 10},
        {name: "john", age: 12},
        {name: "johnny", age: 56}
    ]
```

My below code failed, got expected token?

```
let x = [
    {name: "james", age: 10, school: "London"},
    {name: "john", age: 12, school: "India"},
    {name: "johnny", age: 56, school: "USA"}
]

let y = x.map(obj => {name:obj.name, age:obj.age})

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you are missing the `()` change  like this `({name:obj.name, age:obj.age})`

> You must wrap the returning object literal into parentheses. Otherwise
>   curly braces will be considered to denote the function’s body. Next
>   works:

[**Reference question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

```js
let x = [
    {name: "james", age: 10, school: "London"},
    {name: "john", age: 12, school: "India"},
    {name: "johnny", age: 56, school: "USA"}
]

let y = x.map(obj => ({name:obj.name, age:obj.age}))

console.log(y)
```

Comment: would 
`new Object({name:obj.name, age:obj.age})`
work too?

Comment: @AyoubLaazazi .. Ya of course. But `({})` is enough .short form declaration.

Answer (score 2):

When creating objects with arrow expressions, you'll need to wrap the body in parens, or it'll be parsed as an arrow function:

```
let y = x.map(obj => ({name: obj.name, age: obj.age}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference, this would also work, and be the same:

```js
let x = [
    {name: "james", age: 10, school: "London"},
    {name: "john", age: 12, school: "India"},
    {name: "johnny", age: 56, school: "USA"}
];

let y = x.map(obj => {
  return { name:obj.name, age:obj.age };
});

console.log(y);
```