# destructuring in lambda function returns unexpected value

Tags: javascript, lambda, destructuring

Correct, expected value returned when function used with destructuring:
`[{"k":"key1","v":"val1"},{"k":"key2","v":"val2"},{"k":"key3","v":"val3"}]`

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([{
  k: 'key1',
  v: 'val1',
  z: 'z1'
}, {
  k: 'key2',
  v: 'val2',
  z: 'z2'
}, {
  k: 'key3',
  v: 'val3',
  z: 'z3'
}].map(function(x) {
  let {k, v} = x;
  return {k, v };
})));
```

However, when lambda function is used with destructuring, incorrect value returned:
`[{"k":"key1","v":"val1","z":"z1"},{"k":"key2","v":"val2","z":"z2"},{"k":"key3","v":"val3","z":"z3"}]`

```js
    console.log(JSON.stringify([{
      k: 'key1',
      v: 'val1',
      z: 'z1'
    }, {
      k: 'key2',
      v: 'val2',
      z: 'z2'
    }, {
      k: 'key3',
      v: 'val3',
      z: 'z3'
    }].map(x => 
      ({k, v} = x) )));
```

How would I use destructuring inside lambdas function such that it returns the same as using explicit `function()` above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use destructuring inside of the parameters of the callback of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let array = [{ k: 'key1', v: 'val1', z: 'z1' }, { k: 'key2', v: 'val2', z: 'z2' }, { k: 'key3', v: 'val3', z: 'z3' }];

console.log(array.map(({ k, v }) => ({ k, v })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice! I tried to answer with this but couldn't work out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused beceause this code

```
{k, v} = x;
```

is not actually returning {k, v} but x. So you need to destruct object instead first of returning destructive assigment.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `({k, v} = x)` assigns to the [global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) `k` and `v` variables, and returns the right hand side value `x`. So you've essentially got an identity function `x => x`.

You should use destructuring in the parameters, and build an [object literal as the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object):

```
[…].map( ({k, v}) => ({k, v}) );
```

Comment: I didn't even notice the global variable creation. Nice answer, not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([{
  k: 'key1',
  v: 'val1',
  z: 'z1'
}, {
  k: 'key2',
  v: 'val2',
  z: 'z2'
}, {
  k: 'key3',
  v: 'val3',
  z: 'z3'
}].map(x => {
  let { k, v } = x;
  return { k, v };
})));
```

Comment: Look carefully at Frank's example. He is returning exactly what he wants, that is `return { k, v };`. In your question, you were essentially saying `return ({k, v} = x)` which is different.