# Using spread notation in Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I am trying to get the es6 syntax working for this code fragment.

```
let checkList = [1, 2].map(i => "Check " + i)

let checks = checkList
  // .reduce((acc, check) => Object.assign(acc, {[check]: {valid: false}}), {})
  .reduce((acc, check) => {...acc, {[check]: {valid: false}}}, {})
console.log(checks)
```

The output if i use the commented line in https://babeljs.io is as below and which is what i want to get using the new syntax.

```
Object {
  "Check 1": Object {
    "valid": false
  },
  "Check 2": Object {
    "valid": false
  }
}
```

I am not sure if there is a syntax error in this code. I tried selecting all the presets in babeljs but it does't compile properly.

Comment: It's not ES6 syntax. You cannot use spread syntax in object literals. It's some experimental proposed syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: Keep in mind that spread in reduce [is 
 anti-pattern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object spread is [stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread#status-of-this-proposal) and isn't part of existing specifications. [Stage 3 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) should be enabled in Babel, namely, `transform-object-rest-spread`.

There are syntax errors in the code above that will prevent it from being compiled properly even with required presets.

It [should be](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAxgFiUGsAyBLAzpAvBA2gRgBoIAmAXQDoBbAQwAcAKFCTAPggCIBhORDiAaggoAlAChRoSLHgI0zaD2TowoiBAD06iOQBOIACYBXKCHr1qUKEWmJhzNgHkARgCt4YctTRoUAcwB25pZEAN44NgikAFwQIQBu1MAo-jEAZoloIAC-WcKhuaraekYmZhZWCjJ2rBD0IeQN5UThitGxCUkpEOnAmTl5sbkA3KJQAPb-aGOg5MBjvvQRaMJAA&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D)

```
let checks = checkList
  .reduce((acc, check) => ({...acc, [check]: {valid: false}}), {});
```

Comment: While this works, it's inefficient. Using the spread operator in reduce() is O(n^2) instead of O(n). https://prateeksurana.me/blog/why-using-object-spread-with-reduce-bad-idea/

Comment: It's true. This is the case for older Object.assign, `=> Object.assign(acc, {[check]: {valid: false}})`

Answer (score 5):

First of all you don't have wrap the properties in an extra object (unless you also want to use the spread operator on that).

So `{...acc, {[check]: {valid: false}}}` can become `{...acc, [check]: {valid: false}}`

This means you're adding an object to accumulator. The key of this object is the name you assigned it (`Check[n]`) and the values are the ones you set ({valid...}).

Secondly, as far I know, you cannot use the spread operator without explicitly a new value. So you should either write your state on a new line like:

```
let checks = checkList.reduce((acc, check) => {
  return {...acc, [check]: {valid: false}}
}, {})
```

Or wrap it in extra parentheses:

```
let checks = checkList.reduce((acc, check) => ({...acc, [check]: {valid: false}}) , {})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definitely helped me identify the error.