# JavaScript: Multi line arrow function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, object, return, multiline, arrow-functions

I was given a prompt to follow,
Instructions

Write a multi-line arrow function called gemInfo that takes in three parameters, a gem type, gem size, and  a gem color. Have the gemInfo function return an abject with the values of those parameters set to these three keys, gemType, gemSize, gemWeight.

- Should use arrow function
- Should be a multi-line function

```js
function gemInfo(type, size, color){
  var obj = {
    type: gemType,
    size: gemSize,
    color: gemColor
  };
  return () => obj;
}
```

this is what i have so far and i am at a loss as to what i have wrong, can someone give me any guidance?

Comment: What happened to `gemWeight`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multiline arrow function  would look like this

```
const gemInfo = (gemType, gemSize, gemWeight) => {
  return {
    gemType,
    gemSize,
    gemWeight
  };
}
```

See the official documentation of **[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

Comment: your answer worked but i had to change gemColor to gemWeight, thanks so much

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
var gemInfo = (gemType, gemSize, gemWeight) => {
  return {
    gemType,
    gemSize,
    gemWeight
  }
}
<!-- end snippet -->
this is what they provided as the solution after it was solved

Comment: glad it worked out. Do read the documentation though. Its really interesting and helpful

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `function gemInfo(...) { ... }` isn't an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it's a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). Also, your return value is a `function`, **not an `object`**.

To return an object using the arrow function, wrap the return value in parentheses.

```js
const gemInfo = (gemType, gemSize, gemColor) => ({
  gemType,
  gemSize,
  gemColor,
});

const myGem = gemInfo('diamond', 'big', 'black');

console.log(myGem);
```