# Vue JS: Difference of data() { return {} } vs data:() => ({ })

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, arrow-functions

I'm curious both of this data function, is there any difference between this two.

I usually saw is

```
data () {
  return {
    obj
  }
}
```

And ES6 fat arrow (`=>`) which I typically used

```
data:()=>({
  obj
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: Same thing, you just cant use the arrow way in vuejs for the data func since it doesnt bind this to the right thing inside the vue Obj

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No difference in your specific example, but there is a **very** important difference between those two notations, specially when it comes to Vue.js: **the `this` won't** reflect the vue instance in arrow functions.

So if you ever have something like:

```
export default {
    props: ['stuffProp'],
    data: () => ({
      myData: 'someData',
      myStuff: this.stuffProp
    })
}
```

It won't work as you expect. The `this.stuffProp` won't get the `stuffProp` prop's value (see below for more on the reason why).

## Fix

**Change the arrow function to**, either (ES6/EcmaScript 2015 notation):

```
export default {
    props: ['stuffProp'],
    data() {                                   // <== changed this line
      return {
        myData: 'someData',
        myStuff: this.stuffProp
      }
    }
}
```

**Or to** (regular, ES5 and before, notation):

```
export default {
    props: ['stuffProp'],
    data: function() {                           // <== changed this line
     return {
        myData: 'someData',
        myStuff: this.stuffProp
      }
    }
}
```

## Reason

Don't use arrow functions (`() => {}`) when declaring Vue methods. They pick up the `this` from the current scope (possibly `window`), and will not reflect the Vue instance.

From the [API Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> Note that **you should not use an arrow function with the `data` property** (e.g. `data: () => { return { a: this.myProp }}`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so `this` will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.myProp` will be undefined.

Comment: FYI, a component's `data` function receives the instance as the first argument so you can use `data: vm => ({ myStuff: vm.stuffProp })`

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with ES5 or ES6 syntax, If you have used arrow functions `()=>` in your previous scripts it is safe to use the following codes.

```js
// tested and this.myData can be accessed in the component
data: () => { return {
    myData: 'someData',
    myStuff: this.stuffProp
} }

// this also works
data: () => ({
    myData: 'someData',
    myStuff: this.stuffProp
})
```