# VueJs - Passing variables between methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, reactive, vuetify.js, vue-chartjs

There is a `v-select` component and on change I am firing up `fillData(selected)` where selected is the `v-model`. And I need to update the label in `datacollection.datasets.label` on change. How do I do that ?

```
<script>
  import BarChart from './BarChart.js'
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

  export default {
    name : "TestLegPerformance",
    components: {
      BarChart
    },
    data: () => ({   
      datacollection : {
          labels: ['Week-1','Week-2','Week-3'],
          datasets: [
            {
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: '#C58917',
                data: [40, 50, 20]
            }
          ]
        },
      selected: []

    }),
     computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
        planNames: "planNames"
        })
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getAllPlanNamesAction();
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["getAllPlanNamesAction"]), 
      fillData(selected){
          console.log(selected)
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside methods, you can reference to `data` properties using `this`.

In your case, you can use `this.datacollection.datasets.label` and assign to it:

```
methods: {
  // ...
  fillData(selected){
     this.datacollection.datasets[0].label = selected;
  },
}
```

Of course, this assuming that `selected` is the string you want to assign to the `label`.

**Note:** the `this` will only work when you declare the methods using `methodName() {}` (as you are) or `methodName: function (){...`. So [don't use arrow functions when declaring vue methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data/48981021#48981021), they will mess up your `this`.

## Bind to events using `@` (`v-on`) not `:` `v-bind`)

Your template:

```
<v-select label="Select a Plan" :items="planNames" v-model="selected" single-line max-height="auto" :change="fillData(selected)" required >
```

To listen to the change event, don't use:

```
:change="fillData(selected)"
```

use

```
@change="fillData"
```

Don't send an argument (it will mess things up). `v-select` will send you one already.

Notice the replacement of `:` with `@`.

The first, `:` is an alias to `v-bind`. So `:change="xyz"` is the same as `v-bind:change="xyz"`.

The second, `@` is an alias to **`v-on`**. So `@change="xyz"` is the same as `v-on:change="xyz"`. which is what you want.

[**See demo JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/8bqxxje8/11/).

## Updating `label` of `vue-chartjs`'s `BarChart` automatically

Even though you are

- [using the `reactiveProp` mixin](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data); and
- changing the label

The chart is not reflecting the changes (the label does not change) automatically.

I noticed this happens because **the chart only reacts to whole `datacollection`** changes, not to inner properties (like `label`).

So the solution is to:

- "clone" `datacollection`
- update the `label` of the clone
- assign the clone to `this.datacollection`

And the chart will react (the label change will be reflected).

So, change your `fillData` method to the following:

```
fillData(selected){
    let collectionClone = Object.assign({}, this.datacollection);
    collectionClone.datasets[0].label = selected;
    this.datacollection = collectionClone;
},
```

Check [here a working **DEMO CODESANDBOX** of this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/2p9v32wo5y?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FBarChart.vue) (see the `changeLabelAndReassign()` method of `BarChart.vue`).

Comment: Show your `v-select`

Comment: <v-select
          label="Select a Plan"
          :items="planNames"
          v-model="selected"
          single-line
          max-height="auto"
          :change = "fillData(selected)"
          required
        >

Comment: Thank you but still the label won't change and reflect back in the UI

Comment: Have a look at the demo JSFiddle. In that demo it reflects

Comment: Thanks again and yeah when i put it directly into a div element it changes but what i am trying is to create a bar chart and I am now just trying to change the name based on select.

Comment: Where is that `BarChart.js` from? Maybe the chart simply doesn't react to changes in the `.label` automatically. Maybe you have to call a `.setLabel('new label')` of some sort to change the label.

Comment: I am using VueChart.js and i have a seperate barchart.js

This is the barchart.js.

import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}

Comment: Show your `<bar-chart ..` declaration in the template.

Comment: <v-card>
     <bar-chart class="small" :chart-data="datacollection"></bar-chart>
    </v-card>

Comment: The chart may not be reactive after all !!

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing here and it doesnt seem to be: https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/bLOOBe

Comment: Also, I made a mistake: the correct is `@change="fillData"`, not  `@change="fillData(selected)"`. And also `dataset` is an array: the correct would be `this.datacollection.datasets[0].label = selected;` not `this.datacollection.datasets.label = selected;`. I have updated the question and demo fiddle to fix this.

Comment: Oh let me check that out. Really appreciate the help. Is the label changing now ?

Comment: The label is getting changed but i have to click on the part in the UI where label is there and only then the change is reflected

Comment: By "getting changed" you mean in the chart as well?

Comment: I didn't make changes to the chart part. only the label. The label is changed even in your fiddle once you click on the label where it says 'data one' and changes to 'stuff' once you click on it . Check it out.

Comment: Yeah, but I noticed it does not change in the chart. But I think I know why. It seems you can't just update a `label`, you have to re-set the whole `datacollection` for the chart to react to it. I'm testing this theory now

Comment: yeah exactly !! Fill me in man !! Thank you so much for the help !! Appreciate it

Comment: I believe I got it working. Check the updated answer.