# How to save an existing content?

Tags: vue.js

I can't get how to use `v-html` to save an existing content. For example:

```
<div ref="content" v-html="content">Hello, World! A lot of divs</div>
```

How to make to `div` content was replace only when I will assign a some not `null` value with `content`? Or how to make it in another way? Or is the single way to request `div` content asynchronously?

The next way works, of course, but I lose a data binding.

```
this.$refs['content'].innerHTML = "New content";
```

**P.S.** I am migrating from jQuery and still can't think in Vue.js philosophy clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy, you must read vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html). 
In your component you must declare `content` in `data`, and simply change it in oher places, i.e. in button's click handler or inside component's methods:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: function () {
     return { 
       content: 'Hello, World! A <b>lot</b> of divs'
     };
  },
  methods: {
     changeText: function() {            
        this.content = 'This text from component';
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="root"> 
    <div v-html="content"></div>        
    <button v-on:click="content = 'This text from button'">Click me</button>
    <button v-on:click="changeText">And me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your data should be a method that returns an object when called, otherwise all instances of the component will share the same object and I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: you should not use fat arrow functions when declaring data objects. Vue won't be able to bind this to it and you may run into some issues. See this SO thread for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data

Comment: Thank you, seems I get so I will download it asynchronously still, `v-if` looks simple but it will keep initial content in the memory as I got.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a default value to `content`.

```
data () {
  return {
    content: 'Hello, World! A lot of divs'
  }
}
```

When you'll assign a new value to `content` it will get rendered.

Another way would be to check if `content` is not null and have 2 different divs using `v-if/v-else` for conditional rendering.

```
<div v-if="content" v-html="content"></div>
<div v-else>Hello, World! A lot of divs</div>
```

and the script

```
export default {
  name: 'customComponent',
  data () {
     return {
       content: null
     }
  }
}
```