# What is the difference between 'data:', 'data: ()' and 'data()' in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) docs I've found two ways of defining data so far: `data: {}` and `data() { return; }`.

```
data: {
    defaultLayout: 'default'
}

data() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

So far, I don't have any clue about third ways: `data: () => ({})`. How it makes differ from above two's.

```
data: () => ({
    defaultLayout: 'default'
})
```

Comment: The first one is an object, the second and third are functions that return objects. This isn't Vue specific, just basic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Any difference between second and third?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Comment: The link you pointed to explains exactly the reason why in Vue.js `data` must be a function returning an object. It is in order to avoid passing an object reference which would be modified somewhere else. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an object literal,

```
data() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

is a shorthand for

```
data: function() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

which you can write with an arrow function:

```
data: () => ({
    defaultLayout: 'default'
})
```

Comment: I am sorry, but `regular function` != `arrow function` where scope of keyword `this` differs, and in Vue it may be crucial in certain life cycle stages: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data ; Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data

Answer (score 2):

Only your second example is a valid one. Especially avoid using arrow function for `data` it sets `this`to global so you'll be unable to reference anything from the vue instance.

```
data: () => ({
    someValue = 'default',
    defaultLayout: this.someValue //!!undefined!!!
})
```

The only valid one:

```
data() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are shorthands for returning a value. If you write this code:

```
() => "aaa"
```

It returns "aaa" string. So there is a hidden return statement there. Keeping this in my if we look at:

```
data: () => ({
    defaultLayout: 'default'
})
```

Returns an object which has "defaultLayout" property. Let's look at your first code sample.

```
data() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

is equal to:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    }
}
```

So second and third code samples are almost equal. There is just one difference, arrow functions have lexical "this".

Your first sample is a bad practice. [You can read it about it here.](https://flaviocopes.com/vue-data-function/)