# Assigning props to data in vue

Tags: vue.js

I assigned props to data in vue. But in created hook I am getting the values(group_id and subject_id) in data as undefined and that's why axios.post is giving me error.
I found out that data function is called when vue instance is created, but there is still a little misconfusion.
Is there any way to properly assign props to data so they can be used in created function?

```
props: ['name'], //props passed from route components
data:()=>({
 group_id: name.split("_")[1],
 subject_id: name.split("_")[2]
})
created(){
 console.log(this.group_id, this.subject_id) //log is giving me undefineds
 axios.post(`somelink`, { group_id: this.group_id, subject_id: this.subject_id })
}
```

Comment: just assign props to data in created hook :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible, but it is your code that has some problem.  To access a props you need to use the `this`.  So to access `name` in the data function you would do `this.name`.

This will still produce the undefined.  This is because the scope of the `this` is not the correct one. The scope of the `this` is the vue component and should not be the scope from the caller.  This means that you should not use a fat arrow function.

With these two corrections this would give the following code:

```
props: ['name'],
data(){
   return {
       group_id: this.name.split("_")[1],
       subject_id: this.name.split("_")[2]
   }
},
created(){
 console.log(this.group_id, this.subject_id)
 axios.post(`somelink`, { group_id: this.group_id, subject_id: this.subject_id })
}
```

Comment: thank you for response, I've tried your suggestion and it worked. But I still have some misunderstanding, when I accessed props without `this` it assigned the values to data, but after created hook, I guess. Because in created hook `console.log(this.subject_id, this.group_id)` is giving me undefined but when I looked to the vue component through VUE devtools in browser it is assigned props to data

Comment: After the vue template is parsed, the structure of the `this` is all changed.   I am less experience with the exact details of how the devtool work.  But I would suggest looking at this post to understand scoping of the `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data.  With a fat arrow the `this` scope calling point is what it is used and may be very different from the page and from the tool.