# vue.js API data keeps empty

Tags: php, vue.js

I create a API in php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include '../DBconnect.php';

$rslt = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES");
$songs_random['data'] = array();
while ($db_table = $rslt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, textauthor, musicauthor, genre FROM `$db_table[0]` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";    
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $song_items = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'textauthor' => $row['textauthor'],
            'musicauthor' => $row['musicauthor'],
            'genre' => $row['genre']
        );
        array_push($songs_random['data'], $song_items);
    }
}
echo json_encode($songs_random);
?>
```

An the result looks like this, in browser:

[image: json in browser]

And than I tried to get the data in a vue.js template. This is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-sm text-center mt-4">
        <div class="container-sm mt-3">
            <h3>Hier eine zufällige Auswahl aus der Musik Datenbank.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-sm text-justify mt-5">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.index">{{ item.title }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted(){
    window.addEventListener("load", () => this.songsRandom());
    },
    data: () => ({
        items: []
    }),
    methods: {
        async songsRandom() {
            let apiURL = 'https://gracile-software.de/projects/service-api/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx.php';
            try {
                let response = await this.axios.get(apiURL);
                this.items = response.data;
                console.log(response);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But the list keeps empty and I don't found the issue. What I do wrong? In Console I can see all datas.

Comment: Are there no errors in console?  `:key="item.index"` should be an undefined error because your items have no `index` property.  This error would also very likely prevent your items from rendering.  I think you mean to use `item.id`.  **As a side note**: the `window.addEventListener` is not a good practice in Vue. If you have some event "load" propogating up to this component, you should [listen for it in the template](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html), not on the global `window` object (which adds it App-wide). Otherwise you can use a global bus, or store, or some other strategy

Comment: I've change the key to .id, but there was no error in console. The EventListener ist just for testing, later on I'll change this.

Comment: It could be a problem with `arrow functions` in data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data

Comment: Aint helps if I change the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. The API array() was in the wrong way...

Now it works:

```
$rslt = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES");
$songs_random = array();
while ($db_table = $rslt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, textauthor, musicauthor, genre FROM `$db_table[0]` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";    
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $songs_random[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'textauthor' => $row['textauthor'],
            'musicauthor' => $row['musicauthor'],
            'genre' => $row['genre']
        );
    }
}
```