# amp value replace in place

Tags: javascript, replace, amp-html

I have an amp-list which loads bunch of data and I show them in their respective placeholders just nice and easy. What I intend to do is get a value and run a simple script on it. Let's think I have

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

where title is: 'This-is-my-title'

now I would like to replace the '-' in title, I know I could do it with javascript using `title.replace(/-/g,' ')`, how can I do that in place?
I tried

```
<div>{{title.replace(/-/g,' ')}}</div>
```

but no luck :(

Comment: {{title}} --> which markup/templating engine are you using? Handlebars?

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript the following:

```
title = 'This-is-my-title'; title.replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

gives you `"This is my title"`.

I am guessing you are using angular, in that case  the text within {{ }} is not evaluated as a pure javascript expression. You could write an angular filter to apply to the expresssion (as described in [Angular filter to replace all underscores to spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939288/angular-filter-to-replace-all-underscores-to-spaces) ). It would probably be easier to handle this in the controller behind the template. Something like:

```
$scope.title = $scope.title.replace(/-/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using `amp-mustache`. I don't think there is a way for you to use custom JavaScript in Mustache.js here, and restrictions from AMP prevent you to create some kind of function that you can call in `{{}}`. I would suggest processing in the backend before sending. (Also unfortunately, there are no other templates other than mustache available at this point)

There is a workaround on math using `amp-bind` here: [AMP Mustache and Math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302139/amp-mustache-and-math)
So probably after loading the JSON with `amp-state`, something like

```
myItems.map(entry => ({
  myString: entry.myString.split('').map(c => c == '-' ? ' ' : c).join('')),
})
```

might work (I have not tested myself but worth a try, check whitelisted functions here: https://www.ampproject.org/es/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#white-listed-functions) but might still be a pain performance-wise (amp-bind has quite a bit overhead)

Edit: this actually looks quite promising, just found out actually `amp-list` with `amp-bind` do accept object for `[src]`, as described in the doc (learning something new myself): https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind
(checked `amp-list` source code and should work)