# Short javascript code for property indexed object

Tags: javascript

Can the following javascript code written shorter? It creates a wrapper object with the id property as key and the element itself as value.

```
const f = elem => {
    return {[elem.id]: elem}
}
```

Sample:

```
f({id:'node/1', value:'tmp'})
```

Result:

```
{'node/1': {id:'node/1', value:'tmp'}}
```

I thought about arrow function style `const f = elem => {[elem.id]: elem}`, but Chrome didn't want it.

Comment: `const f = elem => ({[elem.id]: elem})` - as per **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)**

Comment: If you return an object from an arrow function you need more parentheses, to distinguish between the braces that denote a function body and the braces that denote an object: `elem => ({[elem.id]: elem})`. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415/3001761.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: Thank you, I didn‘t see the link, because I thought the computed key is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Bravo said it first, but:

```
const f = elem => ({[elem.id]: elem});
```

works perfectly