# ESLint complains about arrow function return object

Tags: eslint

Why is ESLint rejecting this?

```
let myFunc = (state) => {a:"b"};
```

It is saying that it expected a function or assignment call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow function returning an object literal in this way is syntactically ambiguous, as it could also be a JavaScript block with the label `a` in it. You need to surround the literal with parens to make it clear:

```
let myFunc = (state) => ({a:"b"});
```

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 arrow functions

If you use curly braces `{}`, you should return with a `return` statement.

```
let myFunc = (state) => {
  return { a:"b"}
}
```

If you use don't use braces, you should enclose the return object with round braces `()`.

```
let myFunc = (state) => ({ a:"b"})
```