# Can't execute code within .then callback function?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, axios

How do I execute code at the last comment in the code below? For some reason I'm not allowed to. Isn't my comment within the callback function?

The code is the result of several answers here at Stackoverflow and I don't quite understand what's going on.

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async tab => {

    const contentScriptReady = Promise.all([
        browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "axios.min.js"}),
        browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}),
        browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "sweetalert2.all.min.js" }),
        browser.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, { file: "styles.css" })
    ]);

    const connectionStatus = {};

    async function getConnectionStatusData(logicalAddress) {

        let cooperations = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/cooperations.json', {
        params: {
          connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
          logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId,
          serviceDomainId: serviceDomainId,
          serviceConsumerId: serviceConsumerId,
          include: "serviceContract"
         }
        });

        /* some more let x = await axios.get... */

        connectionStatus.supportedServiceContracts = await Promise.all( cooperations.data.map(cooperation => axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceProducers.json', {
          params: {
            connectionPointId,
            logicalAddressId,
            serviceDomainId,
            serviceConsumerId,
            serviceContractId: cooperation.serviceContract.id,
          },
           }).then(response => ({ // I want to process the response but I can't put executable code here
            serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace,
            serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description,
            serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId,
            }))
          )
        );

        await contentScriptReady;
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, connectionStatus);

    }

});
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: My IDE starts complaining as soon as I try to put any executable code there, but If I put `console.log("test");` there anyway, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`. It refers to the period.

Please not that the problem is at the single line comment, not at the comment block in the middle.

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you get the error.

Comment: I don't get any error as it is, but I do get an error if I try to put executable code where the single line comment is.

Comment: Where are you calling `getConnectionStatusData`? That you are awaiting the `contentScriptReady` which you created outside of the function declaration is suspicious, watch out for unhandled rejections.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! Does that mean that I have to implement the `.catch()` method?

Comment: @RawlandHustle I'm not exactly sure what you're doing here, but if there's a chance that the `contentScriptReady` promise will get rejected before it is `await`ed then it's a good idea to put a `contentScriptReady.catch(err => { … })` directly after its creation. Then either handle the error right there or put only a comment in there stating that it's getting handled later.

Comment: Got you! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [object literal returned from an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415/1048572). You cannot put a statement in there. You will want to rewrite it to

```
….then(response => {
    console.log("example");  // executable code here
    return {
        serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace,
        serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description,
        serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId,
    };
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I read the answer to the question you linked to and I get it now. Appreciate it!

Comment: BTW, is that because it would be double curly braces without it?

Comment: My bad! So only when an arrow function returns an *object*, it has to be wrapped in parenthesis? If so, is that because it would be double curly braces without it?

Comment: Yes, an arrow function with concise body can return any kind of expression but an object literal, which would be mistaken for a block body instead. Even with double curly braces it would not be valid - an object literal cannot be used as a statement.

Comment: Thanks again for explaining!