# Axios interceptors with Typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

How to correctly use axios's inteceptors with typescript:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosInstance } from 'axios'

HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => config)
```

For example, when i create axios instance, i set up default config:

```
const conf: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
}

const HTTP: AxiosInstance = axios.create(conf)
```

But when i try to use interceptor with custom headers:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) =>{
  headers: {
    'x-projectkey': 1234
  }
})
```

It doesn't work:

```
Argument of type '(config: AxiosRequestConfig) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: AxiosRequestConfig) => AxiosRequestConfig | Promise<AxiosRequestConfig>'
```

I'm still new to TS, can't figure this out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the type definition of `AxiosRequestConfig`, you can see that, everything, including axios headers is optional:

```
interface AxiosRequestConfig<D = any> {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method | string;
  baseURL?: string;
  timeout?: number;
  timeoutErrorMessage?: string;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  // ... omited 
}
```

When creating an `axiosInstance` and adding config, the `config` should be returned for the instance to pick up the configuration:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (config.headers) { // <- adding a check 
    config.headers["x-projectkey"] = 1234; // no errors
  }
  config.withCredentials = true; // to include credential, it should be outside of "if" block 
  return config;
});
```

Then in every request you made with the `axiosInstance`, it will include the `x-projectkey` header and credentials:

```
axiosInstance.get("url");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return config like below:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  config.headers['x-projectkey'] = 1234

  return config
})
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you mention you are missing a return.
This should work:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) =>({
  headers: {
    'x-projectkey': 1234
  }
}))
```

Or using the `return` keyword:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) =>{
  return {
    headers: {
      'x-projectkey': 1234
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: While it removes the error, it actually won't pick headers value from interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions.
But in my case that wasn't the problem.
I did return config already.
The issue was much simpler.
The solution was setting `defaultReplyHeaders` when I was creating a nock scope.

Also I've changed the way the OPTIONS request was intercepted.

It works like this:

````
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import nock from 'nock';
import type { Config } from './dependency-injection/config';
import type { ChooseApiRequest } from './api/contract/choose/ChooseApiRequest';
import type { Choice, ChooseApiResponse } from './api/contract/choose/ChooseApiResponse';
import { dy } from './services';

const API_KEY = '6394b44ef96243bf8e6e2aad7f59d389';
const CHOOSE_API_URL = 'https://direct.dy-api.eu/v2/serve/user/choose';

window.dynamicYieldConfig = {
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    chooseEndpointUrl: CHOOSE_API_URL,
} satisfies Config;

describe('Dynamic Yield: services.dy - the DynamicYield facade', () => {
    const CURRENT_URL = 'https://shop.de/';

    const server = nock('https://direct.dy-api.eu/')
        .defaultReplyHeaders({
            'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
            'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
            'access-control-allow-headers': '*',
        });

    it('should provide an abstraction over the `choose` endpoint (independent from cookies)', async () => {
        const CAMPAIGN_NAME = 'campaign';

        // given
        window.pageType = 'Home';
        window.location.assign(CURRENT_URL);

        const expectedRequest: ChooseApiRequest = {
            context: {
                page: {
                    type: 'HOMEPAGE',
                    data: [],
                    location: CURRENT_URL,
                },
            },
            selector: { names: [CAMPAIGN_NAME] },
            options: { isImplicitImpressionMode: true },
        };

        const choiceReturnedByServer: Choice = {
            id: 9999,
            name: CAMPAIGN_NAME,
            type: 'DECISION',
            decisionId: 'decision-id',
            variations: [
                {
                    id: 8888,
                    payload: {
                        type: 'CUSTOM_JSON',
                        data: { 'custom-key': 'custom-value' },
                    },
                },
            ],
        };

        server
            .options('/v2/serve/user/choose')
            .reply(204)
            .post('/v2/serve/user/choose', expectedRequest)
            .matchHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .matchHeader('DY-API-KEY', API_KEY)
            .reply(200, {
                choices: [choiceReturnedByServer],
                cookies: [
                    {
                        name: '_dyjsession',
                        value: 'new-session-id-from-server',
                        maxAge: '3600',
                    },
                ],
                warnings: [],
            } satisfies ChooseApiResponse);

        await expect(
            (async () => {
                // when
                const result = await dy().choose({
                    selector: { names: [CAMPAIGN_NAME] },
                    options: { isImplicitImpressionMode: true },
                });

                // then
                expect(result.get('DECISION', CAMPAIGN_NAME)).toEqual(choiceReturnedByServer);
            })(),
        ).resolves.not.toThrowError();

        // without consent, DY shall not have session persistence with cookies
        expect(document.cookie).not.toContain('_dyjsession');
    });
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as the error message said, is you have a `void` return. This is what you wrote you used:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) =>{
  headers: {
    'x-projectkey': 1234
  }
})
```

The `{` after the `=>` is parsed as the start of a function body. So, you have a function that just has an invalid statement. As @miguelcg [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933983/627486) in their answer, wrap the object with parentheses to return the object directly or use `return`.

Also, you should probably set `headers` ON `config` rather than just returning an object with only your `headers` setting else you will override everything else from the configuration.

I'd suggest this:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => ({
  ...config,
  headers: {
    ...config.headers,
    'x-projectkey': 1234
  }
}))
```

That will leave the remainder of the config intact and not blow away any headers already in there (unless you intended to blow away any headers already in there :-P).

Or, better yet, keep the original class and do this:

```
HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  if (config.headers) {
    config.headers['x-projectkey'] = 1234
  } else {
    config.headers = {
      'x-projectkey': 1234
    }
  }
  return config
})
```