# How should I use map to get back some values of an object when the key are user input

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data as shown below:

```
0: Object { IG: "Low income", FLFPR: 47.00099945, lnGDP: 7.496679918, … }
​​
1: Object { IG: "Upper middle income", FLFPR: 47.67599869, lnGDP: 9.302921813, … }
​​
2: Object { IG: "Upper middle income", FLFPR: 15.18999958, lnGDP: 9.526954146, … }
​​
3: Object { IG: "Lower middle income", FLFPR: 75.47899628, lnGDP: 8.802498179, … }
​​
4: Object { IG: "High income", FLFPR: 47.82500076, lnGDP: 9.858328453, … }
​​
5: Object { IG: "Upper middle income", FLFPR: 51.16600037, lnGDP: 9.011393414, … }
```

I need only say IG and FLFPR from each object. Also, I do not know the values IG and FLFPR. They are user inputs. For example, inputx = IG and inputy = FLFPR.

I tried using map but I couldn't get it to work. I know the below code is incorrect, but intutively this is what I need.

```
xydata = data.map(item => {x: item.inputx, y: item.inputy});
```

Is it right to use map in this context ?

## Edit:

```
    dat = [{x: 8, y: 3, z:5},{x: 2, y: 10, z:5},{x: 11, y: 3, z:5},{x: 6, y: 6, z:5},{x: 5, y: 8, z:5}]
    xText = 'x'
    yText = 'y'  
    xydata = dat.map(item => ({x: item.[xText], y: item.[yText]}));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Comment: you also need this: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access object values knowing key name is enough, You need to use proper key names to access values

change to this

```
xydata = data.map(item => ({x: item.IG, y: item.FLFPR}));
```

Comment: I get a red squiggle around "y:"  . Should I  change the syntax ?

Comment: @learner you need `()` around object (return value of map) , is it showing any error, ?

Comment: Thank You !!! It works ! But I have the values IG and FLFPR in variables. How do I access it ? Maybe "$" would work ? I don't know the syntax to access the value of a variable. Could you please help with it.

Comment: You can use `[]` notation so it will be like this `data.map(item => ({x: item.[variable] ...}));`

Comment: @learner can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have edited the question to include an example. Thank You

Comment: @learner you don't need `.` just use `[]` i.e `xydata = dat.map(item => ({x: item[xText], y: item[yText]}));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` to access object properties dynamically.

```js
let x = {dog: 3, cat: 4, key: 5};
let key = 'dog';

console.log(x.key); // 5
console.log(x['key']); // also 5
console.log(x[key]); // 3
```

In your case:

```
xydata = data.map(item => ({x: item[inputx], y: item[inputy]}));
```

Similarly, you can use `[]` when creating objects with dynamic property names.

```js
let key = 'dog';
let x = {
  cat: 5,
  [key]: 6,
  key: 7,
};

console.log(x.key); // 7
console.log(x.dog); // 6
```

Comment: Thank You junvar ! That was a great explanation ! I finally got it !                                            xydata = data.map(item => ({x: item[inputx], y: item[inputy]}));