# When do we have to use () and {} in ES6 Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I'm little confused with the usage of parenthesis and flower brackets interchangeably in arrow functions.

For instance,

**Use of Flower brackets**

```
const sayHello = () => { console.log('Hello') }
```

**Use of Parentheses**

```
const sayHello = () => ( console.log('Hello') )
```

Both gives same output on the console. Do they both mean same? Sorry if this question sounds dumb.

Comment: Should be `const sayHello = () => ( console.log('Hello') )`

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I just edited my question. Glad, you caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use curly braces (flower brackets) it defines the function body - so you can place multiple semicolon-separated statements inside them. If you wish to return a value from the function, you must explicitly use the `return` statement.

If you use parentheses, you are going to be returning the value of the expression inside the parentheses, and there can only be one expression (with no semicolon). If you wish to do multiple things with parentheses, you can use the comma operator:

```js
const doTwoThings = () => (console.log("Hello"), console.log("Goodbye"));
console.log(doTwoThings());
```

Here, you're logging `Hello`, then `Goodbye`, then you're logging the return value of the function - which is `undefined`.

You can do the same thing inside the curly braces, and you won't see any visible difference:

```js
const doTwoThings = () => {console.log("Hello"), console.log("Goodbye")};
console.log(doTwoThings());
```

Again you're logging `Hello` and `Goodbye` to the console, then you're logging the return value of the function - however, using `{}` needs to have the explicit `return` keyword, so it's `undefined` because we don't return anything from the function.

Also note that sometimes you'll see both parentheses *and* curly braces:

```js
const aFunction = () => ({ foo: "bar" });
console.log(aFunction());
```

There's a nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770578/10221765), but basically when you have a function returning an object, the curly braces `{}` denote the object, and the parentheses enforce the implicit return of the contained expression - the object. So the object is created, then the expression is evaluated and returned.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Now, I get it.

Comment: No problem @Pavan, always glad to help.

Comment: Nit: *"and there can only be one statement (with no semicolon)"* It has to be an expression, not a statement (e.g. you could not do `() => if (x) y`).

Comment: My bad @FelixKling, I always get those two mixed up. Do you have a way of determining which one's which (or have you just memorized the list)?

Comment: Anything that you can put on the left hand side of an assignment is usually an expression. But the ecmascript spec actually separates expressions in two different sections, and just looking at the TOC/menu is useful IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "flower brackets" as you put it, it's like you're defining an ordinary function, having multiple statements as usual. In your example, it runs `console.log('Hello')` and doesn't return anything. When you use parentheses, you can specify only a single expression, and then the result of that expression becomes the return value. In other words, `=> (bar)` is basically the same as `=> { return bar; }`. Both work the same in your case since you're only using that function for its side effects and don't care about its return value.