# Again the error "SyntaxError", but now I follow the answer of my past question

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I have asked about "SyntaxError" in my previous question ([Erro:SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in MUSIC BOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222967/errosyntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-music-bot?noredirect=1#comment111797439_63222967)).  
 I have follow the answer, but in another code, and the error appeared again... I think I went wrong in something on the code... 
 
 I followed what @Emre responded in the music bot, and it worked. But I did it in this code and it didn't work:

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const RichEmbed = require('discord.js').RichEmbed;
const Discord = require('discord.js');

class AddCommand extends Commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'add',
            aliases: ['create', 'new', 'add-suggestion', 'suggestion', 'add-feedback', 'feedback'],
            group: 'suggestions',
            memberName: 'add',
            description: 'Add a suggestion',
            examples: ['add "Add music bot" "Please add a music bot to the server, because it\'s fun!"'],
            guildOnly: true,
            throttling: {
                usages: 2,
                duration: 60
            },
            args: [
                {
                    key: 'title',
                    prompt: 'What is the title of your suggestion?',
                    type: 'string',
                    min: 4,
                    max: 50,
                    wait: 60
                },
                {
                    key: 'description',
                    prompt: 'Please provide a description of your suggestion.',
                    type: 'string',
                    min: 10,
                    wait: 300
                }
            ],
            argsSingleQuotes: false,
        });
    }
    module.exports.run = async ((msg, args) => ({  //here what his responded for me make, put "(" before the "{"
        let channel = msg.guild.settings.get('channel');
        if (!channel || !(channel = messege.guild.channels.get(channel))) {
            msg.react('❌');
            return msg.reply('Sorry, we are not taking new suggestions for the moment.');
        }

       
        const id = msg.guild.settings.get('next_id', 1);
        const formattedId = String(id).length >= 4 ? '' + id : (String('0').repeat(4) + id).slice(-4);

        const embed = new RichEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor(`Feedback #${form.attedId}`, msg.guild.iconURL)
            .addField('Title', args.title)
            .addField('Description', args.description)
            .setFooter(`Posted by ${msg.author.username}#${msg.author.discriminator}`, msg.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setTimestamp();

        
        const suggestion = await channel.sendEmbed(embed);
        suggestion.react('').then(() => suggestion.react(''));

       
        msg.guild.settings.set(`feedback#${id}`, suggestion.id);
        msg.guild.settings.set('next_id', id + 1);

      
        if (!msg.promptCount) msg.react('✅');
        let reply = 'Thanks you for your feedback.';
        if (channel.permissionsFor(msg.member).hasPermission('READ_MESSAGES')) {
            reply += ` You can see it in ${channel} (ID #${formattedId}).`;
        }

        reply = await msg.reply(reply);

        
        if (!msg.promptCount && msg.deletable && reply.deletable) {
            msg.delete(10000);
            reply.delete(10000);
        }

        return reply;
    }); //and here ")" after "}"
}

module.exports = AddCommand;
```

I apologize for asking everything about [discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js) all the time, I'm a very beginner ... lol... If someone can help me, I will be grateful...

EDIT: Sorry for errors, I'm not speak english so much...

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using ^12.2.0

Comment: You seem to be using `RichEmbed`, which has been replaced with `MessageEmbed`.

Comment: hmm... okay man, thanks so much!

Comment: @Daemon Beast Please post this as an answer; it will make it useful for future reference.

Comment: @aDeveloper It's not a full answer though, just something that caught my eye. There are probably more problems with the code.

Comment: The only reason I asked for you to do that was because it solved their problem. And that's an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using **RichEmbed**, which has been replaced with **MessageEmbed**.