# JavaScript. What is the difference between const addName = name => ({firstnmae : name}) and addName2 = (name) => { {firstname : name }}

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am currently learning JavaScript and I have trouble to understand the difference between those 2 functions. I thought they would be equal, but they act completly different.

Function 1 :

```
const function1 = name => ({username: name}) // this is returning a object, even tho there is no 
                                             // return
```

Function 2 : `

```
const function2 = (name) => { {username : name }} // this is returning nothing as expected
```

Comment: Well I think you found the difference.... Read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second function is interesting. The second function doesn't create an object. It is a function with a block `{}` and a [**labeled statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). You can verify it by adding another property to the object literal and it will throw an error:

```js
const function2 = (name) => { { username: name, firstname: name } }
```

It is interpreted like this and this is an invalid label:

```
const function2 = (name) => {
  {
    username: name,
    firstname: name
  }
}
```

---

The first is already explained in many SO questions. It is an arrow function which implicitly returns an object

- [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions)
- [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

A one liner arrow function will return the resulting value.

for instance:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Whereas a multiline arrow function (or one defined using `{` & `}` will not return a value:

```
const add = (a, b) => {
  a + b;
};
```

in order for the above to return a value you will need the return keyword:

```
const add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

**The Confusing Part**

Your case is a bit confusing because you're dealing with an object literal:

```
{ username: name }
```

this syntax represents an "object". Objects in javascript are similar to associative arrays in other languages - that is, they are like arrays with strings as indices. A common example you'll see is something like:

```
const person = { name: 'Joseph', age: 33 }

// output the name:
console.log(person.name);

// output the age:
console.log(person.age);
```

So by wrapping your object literal in parens in your fist example you maintain it as a one line arrow function and your object literal is returned. The second example is really a multiline definition, which will again... have no return value.

Comment: well you forget to mention that you can wrap  the return object in parents to make it work without explicit return statement, which is what the question is actually about `const foo = () => ({retuns: 'object'})`

Comment: @TheFool Wrapping the return object within parentheses has nothing to do with the arrow function. It only serves to notify JavaScript that a expression is following (thus interpreting `{` as an object literal) and not a block. If you don't do this the opening `{` of the object will be read as the opening of the block. This explanation can also be found in [the note for object destructurng](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: I never said it has something to do with the arrow function. I'm saying in essence, this is what was asked about. And you had not mentioned it at all.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that one will not have a return statement while the other one has a short form for the return statement that can be used in arrow function to return objects without exiplicity return statement.

```js
// invalid syntax
const foo = () => {returns: 'object'}

// valid syntax
const foo = () => ({returns: 'object'})


// long form would look like 
const foo = () => {
    return {returns: 'object'}
}
```

The problem is that when you write `foo = () => {returns: 'object'}`, how does the engine know you want to return an object and not open a function body when it sees the {} curly brackets?

To let the engine know it is supposed to be an object that should be returned, you can wrap it in parents.

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions are [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

`Function 1` is an implicit return arrow function, so even though explicit `return` is not used the object `{username: name}` will be returned.

- Function 1

```js
const function1 = name => ({username: name})
```

When using implicit return arrow functions and also an object to be returned, then it should be wrapped in `()`. If we don't wrap it in either `{...}` or `(...)`, then it'll be an invalid syntax

```js
//Invalid syntax --> Will throw an error. Hence it should be wrapper with `()`
const function1 = name => {username: name}
```

But where as in `Function 2` the function definition is wrapped in `{ ... }`. Since there is no return statement in the function, nothing will be returned.

- Function 2

```js
const function2 = (name) => { {username : name }}
```

Comment: In the second function, it is not interpreted as an object https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336371

Comment: Yes you are correct @adiga. Thanks for pointing out.