# How to extract particular key with value from array of objects in typescript/javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below array of object.

`items = [ { id: 0, title: "first item"}, { id: 1, title: "Second item"}, { id: 2, title: "third item"}];`

What I want as another array of object from *items* object :
`idOfItems = [ { id: 0}, { id: 1}, { id: 2}];`

Comment: Isn't this a standard 'array.map' scenario?

Comment: Also relevant: [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the map function.

`const idOfItems = items.map(i => ({ id: i.id }));`

This returns the array in the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

use array.map

```
const idOfItems = items.map(item => ({id: item.id}))
```