# create repeating objects using length of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to create an array of objects based on the length of another object:

```
let initial_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

## Desired Output

```
[
 {width: "5%"},
 {width: "5%"},
 {width: "5%"}
]
```

## What I've tried

I thought I could maybe use a map or forEach to create the repeating object for the length of the initial array but have failed (I'm trying to avoid using a for loop but maybe I need to?)

### This doesn't work

```
initial_array.map(x => {width: "5%"} );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fat arrow syntax is wrong. If you are doing an implicit return with an object you need parenthesis

```
const myArr = initial_array.map(x => ({width: "5%"}) );
```

Comment: You're the one with the gold badge, not me. But hey, you got yours.