# const {} vs const ()

Tags: javascript

```
export const increment = () => ({
  type: INCREMENT
});
```

why is ({}) after => instead of {}? can you give me an explanation or say what's this so I can do my research on this?
Thank you.

Comment: The curly braces on their own denote a _block_. With the parens surrounding them, it becomes an object that is returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an object from a traditional function this would be

```
function increment() {
  return {type: INCREMENT};
}
```

And this works:

```
export const increment = () => {
  return {
      type: INCREMENT
  }
};
```

But this wouldnt

```
export const increment = () => 
  {
      type: INCREMENT
  };
```

If you want to return an object from an arrow function you can wrap it in `()`