# What is this strange Javascript statement "a:3;" and what does it do?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Look at this screenshot:

[image]

I first made a mistake. I know that arrow function can return a value without using the "return" keyword, like `f=()=>3`. I thought that I can use this compact syntax to return an object, like `f=()=>{a:3}`. After trying it, I realised that "{a:3}" in this case is interpreted as the function body, not object literal. Further trying `f=()=>{a:3; return 'three'}` confirmed this: JS interpreted what inside {} as function body, and "a:3" not a property but a statement.

My question is then:

What statement is `a:3;`? What's this syntax? What does it do? I cannot find any reference about it. Very strange...

Comment: Related: [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415)

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) followed by an unused expression.

```
f=()=>{
  a: // label
  3 // expression
}
```

A label means nothing in this case, but it isn't forbidden by the JS syntax (unfortunately).

Comment: Ah thanks..... I forgot about label..... thanks again