# I cant use a part of data directly I have to use another variable in between

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really new to programming and my questions are very really not good
Please forgive me if I am wasting your time
Why when I use labels indirectly in **DatatoBarChartJS** (using a "label") it works

```
const DataFromDataBase  = {
  label :['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets : [  {datasetName:'Dataset 1', data:[1,3,5,2,5,2,6]},{datasetName:'Dataset 2', data:[4,6,5,2,5,2,6]} ],
}
const label =dataFromDataBase.label;
const color = tinycolor();


const DatatoBarChartJS  = {
  label,
  datasets : dataFromDataBase.datasets.map((dataset)=>{
        return{
          label:dataset.datasetName,
          data : dataset.data,
          backgroundColor:color.toRgbString ,
        }     
    }
  )
}
```

but when I use it inderectly it dosnt work?

```
const DataFromDataBase  = {
  label :['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets : [  {datasetName:'Dataset 1', data:[1,3,5,2,5,2,6]},{datasetName:'Dataset 2', data:[4,6,5,2,5,2,6]} ],
}
const label =dataFromDataBase.label;
const color = tinycolor();


const DatatoBarChartJS  = {
  DataFromDataBase.label,
  datasets : dataFromDataBase.datasets.map((dataset)=>{
        return{
          label:dataset.datasetName,
          data : dataset.data,
          backgroundColor:color.toRgbString ,
        }     
    }
  )
}
```

the problem is
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNNiM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I dont get what I expect form the fucntion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71648401/i-dont-get-what-i-expect-form-the-fucntion)

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object using the curly bracket syntax, you usually need to provide the name of the fields and their associated value.

```
const cat = {
  cute: true,
  legCount: 4,
  sound: 'miaw'
};
```

Depending on what "version of Javascript" you are using, there is a shorthand syntax that you can use:

```
const cute = true;
const legCount = 4;
const sound = 'miaw';
const cat = {
  legCount,
  sound,
  cute
}
```

When doing this, the name of the field will be the name of the variable, and the value of the field will be the value of the variable.

The reason you cannot use that syntax in your case is because what you are referencing is not a variable, it's a field within an object. And it kind of makes sense, because the result would be ambiguous:

```
// Would the result be this?
{ DatatoBarChartJS: { label: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'] } }
// Or this?
{ 'DatatoBarChartJS.label': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'] }
// Or this?
{ label: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'] }
```

You can find more information in [Mozilla's object initialization documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)