# Confusion regarding Spread Operator in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So basically I have list of objects. I am iterating and have to change one property of the object. I have two scenarios, in one I have to change the property of a particular object.

```
 setList(list.map((list_item)=>
      list_item.id===id?{...list_item,doubleClick:true}:list_item
    )
```

And there is another scenario where I have to change the property of every object in the list.

```
setList(list.map((list_item)=>{...list_item,doubleClick:false}))
```

The first case is working fine but the second case is throwing error >Parsing error: Unexpected token (34:35)

To me they don't look that different except first one has ternary operator? Is that what's making a difference?
How to fix the second case?

**Edit**: So I think spread operator works with an expression or declaration.

```
setList(list.map((list_item)=>list_item={...list_item,doubleClick:false}))
```

This works.
Is there any better or correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second case, you need to return the new object.

```
setList(
  list.map((list_item) => {
    return { ...list_item, doubleClick: false };
  })
);
```

Or a shorter way is to wrap the new object inside `()`

```
setList(list.map((list_item) => ({ ...list_item, doubleClick: false })));
```

Read more about the syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

**Edit:**

The syntax in the third case is fine but the logic isn't correct. You want to return the new object, not reassign elements in `.map()`