# How can i resolve the syntax error from this code

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, use-state, spread

running the code below throws a syntax error in the console.
it points to the spread operator as an error ,
please how do i fix it?

`import {useState} from "react";`

````
    const [dataInput,setDataInput] = useState({ name: "", age: "", id: "" });
        const nameChangeHandler = (event) =>{
        setDataInput((previousDataInput)=>{...previousDataInput, name:event.target.value})
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={nameChangeHandler} />
            <label>Age (Years)</label>
            <input type="number" />
        </div>
    );
};
export default FormInputs;```



This is the error

Failed to compile.

./src/components/Form/FormInputs.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programs\React\academind\src\components\Form\FormInputs.js: Unexpected token (6:37)

  4 |   const [dataInput,setDataInput] = useState({ name: "", age: "", id: "" });
  5 |           const nameChangeHandler = (event) =>{
> 6 |           setDataInput((previousDataInput)=>{...previousDataInput, name:event.target.value})
    |                                              ^
  7 |   }
````

Comment: setDataInput((previousDataInput)=>({...previousDataInput, name:event.target.value})) you are returning an object implicitly. wrap around with parentheses..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To return an object literal expression requires parentheses around expression:
>
> > params => ({foo: "a"}) // returning the object {foo: "a"}

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

As the doc says if you want to return an object literal expression without the **return** keywoard you need to  enclose the object inside parentheses:

```
setDataInput((previousDataInput)=>({...previousDataInput, name:event.target.value}))
```

Alternatively you can use the **return** keywoard like this:

```
setDataInput((previousDataInput)=>{
 return {...previousDataInput, name:event.target.value};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return an object in setDataInput, not an arrow function