# Create an array of object based on first value as key and second value as value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, lodash

Sample input:

```js
[{'size': '56 X 56 X 190', 'no_of_ups': 5}, {'size': '65 X 55 X 110', 'no_of_ups': 2}]
```

Corresponding ouput:

```js
[{'56 X 56 X 190': 5}, {'65 X 55 X 110': 2}]
```

How do we create an array of Object from input array of Object having fixed number of keys and create new array of Object having certail value of key as key and certail value of value as value of that key.

Basically, We want to transform input array of Object to value of `'size'` as key and value of `'no_of_ups'` as value.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: `const output = input.map(({ size, no_of_ups }) => ({ [size]: no_of_ups }))` This makes use of argument [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

Comment: Are you sure you want that output and not a single object with multiple properties?  eg `{'56 X 56 X 190': 5,'65 X 55 X 110': 2}`

Answer (score 1):

One of the most readable ways of doing this would probably be in normal JavaScript.

```js
const output = input.map(({ size, no_of_ups }) => ({ [size]: no_of_ups }));
```

The expression `({ size, no_of_ups }) => ({ [size]: no_of_ups })` might be a bit confusing, but is just a normal [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

`({ size, no_of_ups })` defines the arguments. In this scenario a single object that we'll [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) into `size` and `no_of_ups`.

`({ [size]: no_of_ups })` is the return value of the arrow function. We'll use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to dynamically set the value of the key and assign it the value of `no_of_ups`.

See [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object) for the reason why the return object has to be wrapped within parentheses.

Comment: Definitely the best answer, imho. Only thing, I'd probably remove the last part if favour of a simple redirection to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770578/5825294).

Comment: @Enlico I've updated the answer removing the explanation of why the object has to be wrapped in parentheses. Pointing to the question that you've linked in you comment.

Answer (score 0):

(If the order of the arguments looks strange, it's because I'm assuming [`lodash/fp` module]
Here's the function that you want to execute on your argument:

```js
f = _.compose(_.spread(_.zipObject), 
              _.unzip,
              _.map(_.over(['size', 'no_of_ups'])));
```

And here it is in action:

```js
arr = [{'size': '56 X 56 X 190', 'no_of_ups': 5}, {'size': '65 X 55 X 110', 'no_of_ups': 2}];
f = _.compose(_.spread(_.zipObject), 
              _.unzip,
              _.map(_.over(['size', 'no_of_ups'])));
console.log(f(arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

And here's a bit of explanation:

- `_.map(_.over(['size', 'no_of_ups']))` runs `_.over(['size', 'no_of_ups'])` on each element,

  - and `_.over(['size', 'no_of_ups'])` simply picks `'size'` and the `'no_of_ups'` of the element and puts the two results in an array), so you get an array of arrays, in this case `[["56 X 56 X 190", 5], ["65 X 55 X 110", 2]]`;
- then `_.unzip` fundamentally transposes the array of arrays, in this case giving you `[["56 X 56 X 190", "65 X 55 X 110"], [5, 2]]`
- finally `_.spread(_.zipObject)` feeds the two inner arrays as comma separated arguments to `_.zipObject`, which constructs objects out of the two arrays, using them as the array of keys and the array of values, thus giving you the final result.

---

If you really want an array of objects rather than a single object, you can change `_.zipObject` for `_.zipWith((x,y) => ({[x]: y}))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Input - [
  {
    'size': '56 X 56 X 190',
    'no_of_ups': 5
  }, {
    'size': '65 X 55 X 110',
    'no_of_ups': 2
  }
]

Input.forEach((val) => { 
  j = {};
  j[val[size]] = val[no_of_ups];
  Output.push(j)
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.