# How to fix .map() function in order to return correct values

Tags: javascript

I have this constant:

```
const foo = {
    1: 'test1',
    2: 'test2',
    3: 'test3'
};
```

I want to use stricly one liner code with function .map()
I tried this approach:

```
...
const options = Object.keys(foo).map((key) => {
        id:key;
        value: getTranslatedText(t, foo[key])
        });

console.log(options);
...
```

But Im getting undefined in `console.log()`:

```
[
    null,
    null,
    null
]
otherwise:
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: undefined
length:3
```

I want to see

```
[
{id:'1', value:'test1' }, {id:'2', value:'test2' },{id:'3', value:'test3' }
]
```

Comment: If you want to return the value, wrap the curlies with parentheses. Otherwise it’s a function body

Comment: Yes, Im trying, based on already existing topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object but its still trows an `undefined`

Comment: You didn't post the code for `getTranslatedText()`. It looks like that's returning `undefined`.