# Angular RxJS Streams HTTP Request - Show more items

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-streams

I'm trying to implement the show more button functionality, when you press it should call the api with the next offset and merge the value with the previous result. From what I saw so far I should use the SCAN function, however I'm lost.

When I click show more the offset is updated

```
public showMore(offset:number){
  this.offset$.next(offset)
}
```

The api is returning this object

```
{
 requestInfo:Info,
 product:Product[]
}
```

Info contains the number of results and the next offset, product contains a list of product (product name, price etc...)

What I tried so far is

```
public getProductsV3():Observable<ProductResponseApi>{

const combineLatest$ = combineLatest([this.offset$,this.limit$]).pipe(
  switchMap(([offset,limit])=>this.fetchProductsFromApiV2(offset,limit))
)

return combineLatest$.pipe(
  scan((prev,current)=> {infos:current.infos,products:[...prev.product,...current.products]} )
)
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work

```
public getProductsV2():Observable<ProductResponseApi>{

return combineLatest$ = combineLatest([this.offset$,this.limit$]).pipe(
  switchMap(([offset,limit])=>this.fetchProductsFromApiV2(offset,limit))
)

}
```

The version 2 is working, however it shows the next pages without keeping the old values.

The fetchProduct is quite simple

```
private fetchProductsFromApiV2(currentOffset:number,limit:number){ 

const params = new HttpParams().set('offset', currentOffset).set('limit', limit);
return this.http.get<ProductResponseApi>(this.apiUrl+'/products',{params,withCredentials:true});
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: your function inside `scan` is not returning anything.  To use implicit return with an object, you need to wrap with parenthesis: `scan((prev,current)=> ({infos:current.infos,products:[...prev.product,...current.products]}))`

Comment: I'm voting to close as typo, your mistake is basically forgetting parentheses around the object you want to return, as BizzyBob mentioned. See also [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)