# Angular RxJS Streams HTTP Request - Show more items - Part 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

Regarding my request about how to implement the show more functionality with SCAN ([Angular RxJS Streams HTTP Request - Show more items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704594/angular-rxjs-streams-http-request-show-more-items)).
How can I merge the response (scan) only when the offset has been updated not when search paramMap is updated ?

My Service that returns the data

```
public getProductsV3(paramMap: Observable<ParamMap>):Observable<ProductResponseApi>{


const combineLatest$ = combineLatest([this.offset$,this.limit$,paramMap]).pipe(
  switchMap(([offset,limit,paramMap])=>this.fetchProductsFromApiV2(offset,limit,paramMap.get('q') as string))
)

return combineLatest$.pipe(
  scan((prev, current) => {
    return {
      infos: current.infos,
      products: [...prev.products, ...current.products]
    };
  })
);
}
```

It works, however when I look for another product using the ParamMap it's combined with the previous result because of the scan. How can I scan only when the offset has changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a response from my question. Thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKsPMTP6-sY&t=970s&ab_channel=JoshuaMorony

```
return combineLatest([paramMap]).pipe(
  switchMap(([search])=> {
    const productForCurrentPage$ = this.offset$.pipe(
      concatMap((offset) =>
        this.http.get<ProductResponseApi>(this.apiUrl+`/search?q=${search.get('q')}&offset=${offset}`)
      )
    )

    const allProducts$ = productForCurrentPage$.pipe(
      scan((prev, current) => {
        return {
          infos: current.infos,
          products: [...prev.products, ...current.products]
        };
      })
    )

    return allProducts$;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `withLatestFrom`

```
const combineLatest$ = combineLatest([this.offset$,this.limit$]).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(paramMap), 
  switchMap(([[offset,limit],paramMap])=>this.fetchProductsFromApiV2(offset,limit,paramMap.get('q') as string))
)
```

or `take`

```
const combineLatest$ = combineLatest([this.offset$,this.limit$,paramMap.pipe(take(1))]).pipe(
  switchMap(([offset,limit,paramMap])=>this.fetchProductsFromApiV2(offset,limit,paramMap.get('q') as string))
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried both and the fetchProduct doesn't trigger when param change

Comment: " Expected behaviour : When a new params is emmited the scan shouldn't be triggered" I thought that is what you wanted?

Comment: The scan (merging current and previous result together) but it should at least trigger the fetchProductFromApi

Comment: I'm not explaining correctly. When user search a new product then it should return a new observable object and in the front the user can show more items but when he enter a new query in the search then the scan should not be in use.