# Assign a new property to an object inside an explicit function (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I'm just starting to learn JS. I need to redo this function into an explicit one. As a result, the property should be added to the object. And please explain how it works.

```
const newPost = (post, addedAt = Date()) => ({
    ...post,
    addedAt,
})

const firstPost = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max'
}

console.dir(newPost(firstPost))
```

That's all I could think of. There are no further ideas

```
const firstPost = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bogdan'
}

const newPost = (addedAt = Date(), ...post) => {

    return post
}

newPost(firstPost)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit function"?

Comment: Your first code snippet seems to run fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I need to pass this function with the construction function {}. Without parentheses

Comment: not clear what you mean, or why you'd need/want to avoid parenthesis. But see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415/1048572 for syntax alternatives - or just use `function`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.