# How to return lowercase text in a javascript arrow function without using a return in the statement body

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, arrow-functions, lowercase

I am solving a problem for school. The problem instructs me to: "create and arrow function with the following:

> 1. accepts a parameter
> 2. does not use the return keyword
> 3. returns text passed to it as lower case (with method toLowerCase() ) "

The code should be passed:

`getLowerCase('MY UPPERCASE TEXT');`

There are three test cases it must pass:

> 1. "getLowerCase does not use a return"
> 2. "getLowerCase returns lowercase text"
> 3. "getLowerCase is a valid arrow function"

I tried a few cases, but in my mind, they all require a return statement. I'm newer to javascript (used python previously) and I am easily confused as to how to return a value without use a return keyword explicitly.

```
const getLowerCase = text => {
  return text.toLowerCase();
  // this should make sense, but uses a return statement
};

const getLowerCase = text => {
  getLowerCase: text.toLowerCase 
}
// probably gobbly-goo, tried reading this posting, might have gotten lost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object?noredirect=1&lq=1
```

Comment: `const getLowerCase = text => text.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Presumably they want you to use the _implicit_ return, read up on the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, a single statement do not require a return statement for arrow functions:

```
const lowercase = n=>n.toLowerCase();
```

The JavaScript engine automatically interprets the statement inside the function as an expression and returns the result of that expression immidiately.

Comment: Not every statement can be interpreted as an expression.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was hoping for a "deeper" explanation on how or why that occurs, but stack overflow saw this as someone just looking for a quick answer. Maybe I should have been more specific.