# How can I map a list to a list of JSON?

Tags: typescript

I try to cast a list of strings [x, y, z] to
a list of JSON-objects [{str:x},{str:y},{str:z}].

Thats my try, but I get an error.

```
let lst:string [] = ["a", "b", "c"];

let foo:any [] = lst.map (l => {"str": l});
```

Error

```
error TS1005: ';' expected.
  let foo:any [] = lst.map (l => {"str": l});
                                       ~
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax would not work with Javascript either

You want

```
const foo:({ str: string })[] = lst.map (l => ({"str": l}));
```

You need to escape the `{}` that looks like a function body, and make Javascript think it is dealing with an object

Answer (score 1):

In your Code, you missed adding a return to the object:

```js
let lst: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];

let foo: any[] = lst.map((l) => { return { "str": l } });

console.log(foo)
```

TIP: Add `{ return { "str": l } }` when you map.

`.map()` returns a new array with each element resulting from the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

While returing you need to use brackets(). Because we are inside a loop {} will be treated as block. So the updated code will be,

```
let lst: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];

let foo: any[] = lst.map(l => ({ "str": l }));
```

Note **(**{"str": l}**)**