# React JSX iterate over array of string and print message

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a function component as below:

```
const MyFunctionComponent = ({status}) => {
let consolidatedErrorMsg = status.errorMessage.split("-"); //['Error line 1', 'Error line 2']
    return (
        <div>
            {status.status && (
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <Icon
                            name={status.status === 'success' ? 'success' : 'error'}
                        />
                    </p>
                    {
                        consolidatedErrorMsg.forEach((msg, i) => {
                            <div>{msg}</div>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Now, within this function component, I am trying to iterate and print `consolidatedErrorMsg`, which is an array of strings as I have shown above. However, for some reason, it is not working. Seems like some syntax issue while iterating.

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting? Secondly like @0stone0 said you are not returning any jsx currently. Use `consolidatedErrorMsg.map(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) since `forEach()` does nothing with it's returned value.

You've also used `{}` so add the `return` keyword, or replace with `()` as shown in the demo below.

---

- [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)
- [Don't forget to add a unique key when rendering lists](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists)

---

```js
const MyFunctionComponent = () => {

    const consolidatedErrorMsg = ['Error line 1', 'Error line 2'];

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {
                consolidatedErrorMsg.map((msg, i) => <div key={msg}>{msg}</div>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyFunctionComponent />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```